# Blur content behind div tag when background centred

Tags: jquery, html, css, blur

I know this has been asked before and I have been able to blur content behind a div tag, but when the background is centred, Blur.js doesn't pick up that the background has been centred and continues to blur it as if the background was the full sized image.

The problem can be seen here: http://home.josephftaylor.com/cadets/

Comment: Providing JSFIDDLE and your code may help...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GJDMT/ I can't seem to stop it from showing the local image error or get it to show the blur div.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some bug that doesnt cooperate with background: center no-repeat
here's example when I just put

```
        #container{
            position: absolute;
            background: url(bg.jpg);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

And it works fine, I dont know why you put background: fixed, what was the purpose?

[EXAMPLE](http://revelier.home.pl/Examples/blur/)

Comment: I need it to have the background centred and resize according the the browser size. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking around and tryin solve it but seems I cannot. Sorry

Comment: What about if I had a blurred version of the background image and set that as the background of the div and found a way to match the positioning? I've done a lot of messing around and I'm still struggling to find an answer.

Comment: Im wondering if you have to got this plugin or could it be something different? Cuz it seems that plugin load normal size of background and then browser fit it as cover and background dont match. I'll think more about that problem later :) cheers